# How can I repeat content (aka *ngFor) without a wrapping element?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 4 component that uses what is effectively a 2d array. I have an array of sections which hold an array of links. I want to be able to output them all flatly:

```
<ul>
  <div *ngFor="let section of all_sections">
    <li *ngFor="let nav of section.links" [class.active]="nav.href === current_url">
    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

How can I force it to do the loops but without the extra wrapping div for the sections? It should just be li tags inside the ul.

Expected output:

```
<ul>
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what do you mean by this **How can I force it to do the loops but without the extra wrapping div for the sections**

Comment: Updated to include expected output

Answer (score 43, accepted):

you can try using ng-container

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let section of all_sections;">
 ...
</ng-container>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, not to be confused with `<ng-content>` which is used for content (or multi-slot) projection..